# Function callback, local variables and chrome.storage.sync.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

This is more of an aesthetic question than an actual issue. The code suggested by Google works fine. However, I don't feel comfortable writing it.

When you write Google Chrome extensions, you can use permanent storage. It's retrieved using a certain function, like this:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("cake", function(result) {
    alert(result["cake"]);
});
```

This is alright. Now if you want to iterate a lot of values from the storage, it could go like this:

```
var keys = new Array("cake", "pie", "squirrel");
$.each(keys, function() {
    var key = $('<div>').append(this).html(); // ignore this line
    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function(result) {
        alert(result[key]);
    });
});
```

This works perfectly well. Except I can't shake the thought that you're technically using a callback function that uses a local variable of the outer function that's being changed by the iteration. I'm going to assume it's impossible for the callback to happen after it's finished that iteration cycle, but in other situations (eg. the jQuery click event) you could end up using the wrong value of the key variable.

This would be fine if you could retrieve the key from the result at all times. Like this:

```
var keys = new Array("cake", "pie", "squirrel");
$.each(keys, function() {
    var key = $('<div>').append(this).html(); // ignore this line

    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function(result) {
        var key;
        for (key in result) {}

        alert(result[key]);
    });
});
```

But you can't if it doesn't find an existing value in the storage. Instead of returning an object that has a property set to null, it returns one with no properties at all (so you can't get the property's name). This leaves you with no way to retrieve the originally queried key within the function.

It's a non-issue, I guess, as it works anyway. I just don't like writing stuff like this. Or am I wrong in thinking this is weird code? Or perhaps there is a way to do it more properly?

Comment: What's the issue? I read your question twice, but I can't tell with certainty what you're asking. However, I've got a strong feeling that you find it interesting that it's possible to read/write multiple keys at once, by passing a dictionary (with defautl values).

Comment: Each invocation of the outer callback function will create a separate closure, so the name `key` in the inner function will always be bound to the correct value. There is no way you can "end up using the wrong value of the key variable".

Comment: @rsanchez I'm not following. If it works exactly like you say, then this code (http://pastebin.com/bZqJauk6) would work. Except all five elements will return 5 when you click them.

Comment: @JeffreySmith no, in your question you are declaring a variable in the body of the outer function. That variable will be instantiated as many times as the outer function is called. In the last example you propose the situation is completely different. Here's a fiddle of an adaptation of your last example to resemble the structure of the code your question: http://jsfiddle.net/yCJhR/2/

Comment: @rsanchez Good point. I actually incidentally added that line to cast the object to a string (otherwise the get function wouldn't work), but it does indeed also change/fix the situation. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have quite a strange problem. [StorageArea.get](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get) accepts key or array of keys as first parameter. So you can write your code like this:

```
var keys = ["cake", "pie", "squirrel"];
chrome.storage.sync.get(keys,function(result){
    keys.forEach(function(key){
        alert(result[key]);
    }) 
});
```